# Facebook Connect, jQuery UI, and jQuery.noConflict()

Tags: jquery, facebook, api, jquery-ui

I'm trying to build a page on my personal website that both used `jQuery` and implements `Facebook Connect`.

Unfortunately, the `Facebook client API` uses the `$ token`, which means I have to call `jQuery.noConflict()`

Double-unfortunately, I've found out that for some crazy reason and [as Rick Strahl points out, jQuery UI doesn't respect noConlict(). At all.](http://web.archive.org/web/20070722183917/http://west-wind.net/WebLog/posts/157705.aspx) In fact, if you look at the source code, there are `$`s all over it.

I *really* want to be able to use jQuery UI - specifically, the `dialog()`component, and `draggable` would be really nice as well - but I even moreso, I don't want to have to hand-edit - and test, and maintain - my own copy of any part of jQuery UI.

This is the most recent in a series of [yaks I've had to shave](http://projects.csail.mit.edu/gsb/old-archive/gsb-archive/gsb2000-02-11.html) which has me at my wits' end. Any suggestions? Help!

Comment: What version of the Facebook Connect API are you using?  I just downloaded it and it looks like it is using FB, not $ throughout.  Maybe I'm missing something, though...

Comment: Not sure what you mean... I just followed their documentation for implementation. Before I started using noConflict(), I was getting weird method/object does not exist errors from the Facebook stuff. Don't recall what the actual errors were though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The post you've referenced is quite old and out of date. The `1.0` release of `jQuery UI` had this issue in a couple of files and was fixed as soon as it was reported.

All of jQuery UI is wrapped in a `closure` that passes in jQuery as `$` and therefore can use $ internally while $ is used for something else externally.

From http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries#Referencing_Magic_-_Shortcuts_for_jQuery

> Use the following technique, which allows you to use $ inside of a block
>   of code without permanently
>   overwriting $:
>
> ```
> (function($) {
>   /* some code that uses $ */
> })(jQuery)
> ```

Note: If you use this technique, you can still use Prototype via `window.$` e.g., `window.$('some_element_id')`. Any function outside of your closure that references `$` will invoke Prototype, even if called from inside your closure.

This is why you'll see `$` inside the jQuery UI files, but rest assured, any recent version of `jQuery UI (1.5+)` is completely supported with `jQuery.noConflict()`