# MooTools is messing Facebook JavaScript SDK

Tags: javascript, mootools, facebook-javascript-sdk, apprequests

I have the page which has MooTools used in the page and I have added facebook sdk too.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.3.0/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>
```

and in the body it is like this.

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'myappid',
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true, // parse XFBML
        oauth      : true
    });
</script>
```

For sending FB invite request I use.

```
FB.ui({
            method: 'apprequests',
            message: 'tests messages',
            //title: 'Invite you friend to MyApp',
            to: fbid
        },function(r){ console.log(r);  });
```

But this gives me "a is null" in all.js file. If I remove MooTools file, everthing works fine. But I need MooTools. How can I get fix for this problem? Any help please?

Comment: This post may help http://stackoverflow.com/q/392334/778687

Comment: Thanks ... It just solves the problem of $ conflict. Though I tried it, but that doesn't help me.

Comment: Ops.. I realized the problem is not jQuery. Its because of Moo tools. Any help on that

Comment: that's why using jquery conflict is necessary. just answered a question like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597442/convert-jquery-code-to-mootools-1-11/9598672#9598672

Comment: Cant you use jQuery for what mootools is doing OR mootools for what jquery is doing? I see this a lot and it always seems senseless and wasteful to include 2 very powerful yet large libs into an app or site...

Answer (score 0):

you load mootools AFTER jquery. this means that it won't take over `$` and will fall back to its own noConflict mode, the selector remaining aliased as `document.id` only.

either all your mootools code needs to use that, or use the simple closure pattern that affords use of `$` to `document.id` in mootools.

```
$; // jQuery
(function($) {
    $; // mootools
})(document.id);
```

other things to consider when using mootools: it's prototypical. make sure you don't do stupid stuff like, for ... in loops on Arrays w/o hasOwnProperty checks (bad idea to begin with but it's more widespread than one would think...)

aside from the above, you need to track it down to a specific bit of code that fails. it will likely be that you are passing the jQuery function to what mootools thinks is an element, eg, `$('foo')` when that's jQuery won't return the element object. Even `$('#foo')` won't work but `$('#foo')[0]` will.